# Windows.open in chrome

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm trying to use [this](http://www.pink-seo.com/blog/liste-deroulante-et-referencement-68) in a website, it's for SEO needs ... It work well but this code :

```
window.open(url)
```

Don't produce the same result in all browser, in FF and IE, it create a new tab but in Chrome it open a new window and in Safari it didn't work at all.

Any idea to fixe it or another way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a browser option. You can't really control that. Check the browser settings for tab operation.

Comment: So if i want to make it work in all browser i need to do an if statement for each browser ?

Comment: No, that's not something that you can control via javascript. If your users select to have pop-ups open in a new tab, your code can't alter that.

Answer (score 0):

Browser settings control how window.open works. It can pick to open in a tab or a new window and there is nothing in JavaScript that can override that.

Comment: not true, by setting the width in the window.open() at least firefox will open a new window instead of a tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you set some options that don't 'fit' the main window, a new window will open instead of a new tab. Tried with the width setting and ff6 and ie7.